# Universal Windows Project, VS17, Cannot Install Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client IOT SDK

Tags: azure-iot-sdk

I'm getting the following failure report when attempting to install version 1.31.2 in VS17 using Nuget.

Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client 1.31.2 is not compatible with uap10.0.15063 (UAP,Version=v10.0.15063) / win10-arm [and other Windows 10 versions]. Package Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client 1.31.2 supports:

- net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
- net472 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2)
- netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
- netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)

Any advice on how to resolve this would be appreciated. Do I need to use and earlier version?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to meet the OS and hardware compatibility as described to install and use Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client :

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp#os-platforms-and-hardware-compatibility

[image]

See also: [Prepare your development environment](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/master/doc/devbox_setup.md#prepare-your-development-environment)

"**Visual Studio is not required to build the SDK**. This may not be sufficient to run certain samples that require Visual Studio and other SDKs or frameworks installed on your machine."